# Ways to order all possible videos, between $90$ minutes and $3$ hours long

Tags: combinatorics

Let's say you could generate all possible videos, assuming that each pixel can display $16,777,216$ possible colors, a monitor size of $1920\times1080$ pixels, a frame rate of $24$ frames/second, and all run-time between $90$ minutes and $3$ hours long.

In how many different orders could you show the resultant films?

I'm pretty sure it's involves factorials, but I'm not sure how to compute it.

Comment: This reminds me of a [spiked-math comic](http://spikedmath.com/420.html).  It will rely on the [rule of sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_sum) and the [rule of product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of possible frames is 
$$
F = 2^{\, 24 \, \times \, 1920 \, \times \, 1080}
$$
The number of possible movies of $n$ frames is $F^n$.

By “all run-time” I guess you mean $n$ can be any integer from $90 \times 60 \times 24 = 129600$ to twice that, inclusive; so the number of all movies is

$$
M = F^{129600} + F^{129601} + ... + F^{259199} + F^{259200} = \frac{F^{129600}\, (F^{129601}-1)}{(F-1)}
$$

The number you asked for is $M!$.

Comment: A more interesting question imho, since I wouldn't want to sit through all possible truncations of even a good movie:  What's the minimum length of a meta-movie that includes (overlapping) all possible 3 hour movies, and how many versions of it are there?

Answer (score 1):

Lets break it down into steps:

- How many possible frames exist?  Since each frame is a specific choice of color for each pixel, it will be $16777216^{(1920\cdot 1080)}$.  Let us simplify this by referring it as the number $F$.
- How many possible ways can you form a second's worth of footage?  Since for each second of footage, you have $24$ frames, and for each frame you have $F$ possibilities, there are then $F^{24}$ different ways to have a second of footage.  Let us refer to this number as $S$.
- How many possible ways can you form a video that is $T$ seconds long?  Since for each second, there are $S$ possible videos, there are $S^T$ possible videos.  Let us refer to this as the number $f(T)$
- How many videos are between 90 minutes long and 3 hours long?  Let us assume to simplify things that every video has an exact number of seconds of playback (a similar argument works if you allow fractions of seconds).  90 minutes is 5400 seconds, while 3 hours is 10800 seconds.  Since if two videos are of different length, we count them as different, we can sum over all possible video lengths.  There are then $\sum\limits_{T=5400}^{10800}f(T)$ different videos that meet your description.  Let this number be called $M$.
- If we wish now to organize all of these movies into a playlist (or shelf or lineup or whatever), there are then $M!$ ways to arrange them.

This is a very...*very* big number, but still technically finite.

Comment: Is there a method to convert F and M to scientific notation? I'm assuming that representing M! in base ten is beyond possibility, no?EDIT: There any way of of conveying (notating?) how very very big M! is?